# Can`t Update or Delete when using Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I would like to ask how to customize active admin.
I`m making my own blog and creating admin page using active admin gem.
This has many to many relationship with article and tag through article_tag table.

What I want to do is to add tag from article panel and I was able to show tag view in article panel, but it is not working fine.(I can`t update or remove tag after save once)

http://localhost:3000/admin/articles/new

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5odoQ.png)

I made the many to many relation with Article and Tag model like this.

article.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :article_tags
    has_many :tags, through: :article_tags
accepts_nested_attributes_for :article_tags, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

tag.rb

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :article_tags
    has_many :articles, through: :article_tags
end
```

article_tag.rb

```
class ArticleTag < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :article
    belongs_to :tag
end
```

And I customized active admin like this.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Article do

permit_params :title, :description, :url, :image_url, :media, article_tags_attributes: [:article_id, :tag_id, :name, :_destroy, :_edit]

form do |f|
    # f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
      f.inputs "Admin Details" do
      f.input :title
      f.input :description
      f.input :url
      f.input :image_url
      f.input :media
      f.input :publish
    end
    f.inputs "Articles" do
      f.has_many :article_tags do |t|
        t.input :tag
      end
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

But after I saved the article with tag once I can`t update tag or delete tag...
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Please don't use pseudo-tags like "【Ruby on Rails】" in titles.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to permit `:id` attribute of article_tag object. It is passed when updating/deleting existing nested object.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Article do
  permit_params :title, :description, :url, :image_url, :media, article_tags_attributes: [:id, :article_id, :tag_id, :name, :_destroy, :_edit]
  ...
end
```

Comment: I always forget to do this, then it just magically doesn't work.  
It's important to remember this step when adding a new column.